# Как можно раздекопилировать билд и открыть его на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть таренька игрушка, давно валяеться уже никто не играет как можно открыть её на юнити ?

Она была написана на движке Unity, остался билд с открытым кодом!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если билд с открытым кодом, то почему "декомпилировать"?

Comment: Я просто не понимаю как вытаскивать с AsemblerCharp асеты и так далее. Вот хотелось бы её разобрать. А так в ней нету ничего закодираваного!